# Remove Files of Certain Extension From Git Tracking After Staging

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I am wondering if it is possible to remove files of specific extensions after they have been added to Git tracking.

Specifically, I have a .gitignore that already eliminates these files. However, as a result of a mishap, they may have been added to tracking. My plan now is to go and run `git rm --cached` on all directories and files specified in .gitignore. But I am having a difficulty addressing entries specified as file extensions.

Comment: this gets a list of newly added files that are in the index (ie newly tracked?)  'git diff --cached --diff-filter=A --name-only'.  This may help if the mishap added extraneous files, and the intentional commit did not.  Otherwise git rm --cached -- *.xxx should remove the file from the index according to my reading of git help rm

Comment: Would git rm --cached -- *.xxx do this for all files and all (sub) directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `find` for this, since it allows you to both specify a pattern of a filename (including *.extension*) and execute a command on that file.

Here's an example that does the procedure manually, for one file extension at a time:

```
/tmp/madphys $ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/madphys/.git/
/tmp/madphys HEAD$ touch lala.a
/tmp/madphys HEAD$ touch lala.b
/tmp/madphys HEAD$ mkdir dirdir
/tmp/madphys HEAD$ touch dirdir/bobo.a
/tmp/madphys HEAD$ git add .
/tmp/madphys HEAD$ git commit -m first
[master (root-commit) bfc10f1] first
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dirdir/bobo.a
 create mode 100644 lala.a
 create mode 100644 lala.b
/tmp/madphys master$ echo "*.a" > .gitignore
/tmp/madphys master$ git add -A .
/tmp/madphys master$ git commit -m ignore
[master 3e0d206] ignore
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
/tmp/madphys master$ find . -name "*.a" -type f -exec git rm --cached {} \;
rm 'dirdir/bobo.a'
rm 'lala.a'
/tmp/madphys master$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    dirdir/bobo.a
    deleted:    lala.a

/tmp/madphys master$ git commit -m "removed"
[master 87d95d6] removed
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 dirdir/bobo.a
 delete mode 100644 lala.a
/tmp/madphys master$ tree
.
├── dirdir
│   └── bobo.a
├── lala.a
└── lala.b

1 directory, 3 files
/tmp/madphys master$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed tutorial! When I follow it, after I delete bobo.a and lala.a and run "git status" mine says "Changes not staged for commit" instead of "Changes to be committed." Am I doing something differently?

Comment: Actually, I think I missed one of the commands, so I shall retry it.

Comment: Just to clarify, is there a fundamental difference between "git rm" and "rm"?

Comment: That is, in the command involving "find," do you remove the files from git repository only or also from the physical directory?

Comment: `git rm` removes files, but `man git rm` says this about `--cached`: "Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone." "Working tree files" would then be what you get with a regular `rm`, and after that, you would need to `git add` (track, really) the deletion of all those files, `git rm` does that for you.

Comment: I am coming back to this. Just to be sure, what should I use if I want to remove files from tracking, but not from the actual file system? Is it `man git rm` ?

Comment: It's `git rm --cached` you are after. `man` is the command and reference to a man page, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page . I think it's only applicable to you if you use OSX, Linux, BSD or such, or Cygwin if you're on Windows.